# Will there be hats this winter (2015)?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, winterbash, winterbash-2015

People like hats.  Will there be hats? Will there be new hats? Hats?

Comment: I appreciate your enthusiasm for the Winterbash. We have not yet officially committed the site to the festivities this year, so let this be the mod-sanctioned Meta post: do we want to participate in the Hat Dash this year?

Comment: Gloves. I recommend gloves, too.

Comment: [Yes](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4247089#4247089), if it does begin. Well, the biggest secret of this year's Winter Bash isn't what hats there will be. It's that who the Hat Czar is, since [Jon stepped down](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4229469#4229469).

Comment: @Mitch: But not mufflers. Everyone at EL&U must continue to speak freely and without the inhibiting obstruction of excessively large scarves.

Comment: I'm most interested in what our esteemed moderator, [@nohat](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/users/39/nohat) has to say on this subject!

Comment: @AndyT You know that's how he got his name, right?

Comment: I don't like hats.

Comment: I hope so because [hats are absolutely vital.](https://i99.photobucket.com/albums/l302/Chris_Lv255/1219194994320_zpsfdb23624.jpg)

Comment: This is a comment.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> People like hats.

Okay, um, that's... not really a question, but, we can start off slow. Yes! True. Correct. People do, for the most part, like hats.

> Will there be hats?

What sort of tradition-breaking libertines do you take us for? Hats are coming, friend*.

> Will there be new hats?

**There sure will!** In fact, we will be bringing you an all-new assortment of hats for your avatar-decorating needs, as we have done every year since the very first year of Hat Dash, 2011. (This is because we love you, and certainly *not* because we forget where we store the old hats every year, like so many squirrels with their nuts. Nope, nope, nope.)

> Hats?

Haaaaats!

* <sub>assuming the community consensus is pro-hat</sub>

Comment: Maybe shoes to cover my blue feet?

Comment: This is Stack Exchange, @bluefeet. Second Life and Blizzard are over that way.

Comment: Huzzah! But, out of interest,  how many sorts of tradition-breaking libertines *are* there?

Comment: In a break with tradition, only one.

Comment: I don't like hats

Answer (score 0):

I am [cocklaphobic](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Cocklaphobia).

No head thingies round here, please.

Comment: You will be able to signal your fear of shellfish when hats are implemented, and never have to see them. Or hats. Actually, I'm not sure about cockles: they may not be affected.

Comment: It seems the rest of the community has overruled you on this one, but as Andrew pointed out, you will be able to stop yourself from seeing hats. After the event starts, click on the snowflake icon in the top bar (it'll be next to the usual notification and rep change icons) and look on the bottom left of the pop-up for an "I hate hats" link.